# Assign Primary key the correct way

Tags: sql, popsql

I have assigned the primary key to my first column but when i run the 'DESCRIBE' command it is a success but i cannot see on the describe table that a primary key has been assigned.

How do I assign a primary key properly?

[Pop SQL image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iB4u5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The primary key should be a not nulled field. You can try this query.

```sql
create TABLE register (
    student_iden INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    naam VARCHAR(20),
    course VARCHAR(20)
);

DESCRIBE register;
```

Comment: Ir still does not solve the problem for me it instead gives me this error. 

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'register' at line 1
Error Code: ER_PARSE_ERROR

Comment: Whats your mysql version?

Comment: I am using 5.7.20-log

Comment: Dont matter i already sorted out the problem.